# Word for continuous crying

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Is there an exact word to describe "*Sudden, loud crying / sobbing, with hiccups and gasping for air*"?
 (To describe someone who woke up crying from a bad dream)

Comment: What makes the "sudden, loud crying with hiccups" related to "waking up with tears all over your face"?

Comment: @TasneemZh No, not just tears but loud crying or sobbing with audible voice

Comment: So the word you need is not necessarily related to describing that situation, I assume.

Comment: @TasneemZh no, but I added the example because I had to use the word in that situation.

Comment: Would **high-pitched cry** make a good equivalent to your definition?

Comment: @TasneemZh No, sorry. Not even close.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the word [Blubber](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blubber). This might fit your requirements.

Comment: Seems like it fits, but I haven't used it, so just to be sure, is it a formal word? Like, formal enough to be used in essays or such?

Comment: To me "Blubber" sounds colloquial. Though in [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/blubber?family=blubbering) "blubbering" is shown to have been used by some well known newspapers.